# Saving small text files is slow over Win Server 2008 R2 VPN

Tags: windows, vpn

We have a VPN connection to our Windows Server 2008 R2 machine, and the connection works fine. Large files go back and forth fairly quickly, but we use the connection mainly for working on small text files (.aspx, .asp, .php etc).

What we find very annoying is that even the smallest of files, there is a noticeable delay of between 2-5 seconds when saving any changes.  As we often make changes to code and are constantly saving, this is becoming a problem.

Is there anything that might be causing this delay? Or is there anything we can do to speed it up?

The connection is definitely not the issue as we have a constant 5Mb upload from our server, and 20Mb+ down on the remote machines.

Thanks,

Chris.

Comment: Sounds like a classic MTU problem.  Let us know your MTU by using the following command: ping -f -l 1472 <server ip>  You may need to reduce 1472 until you get a response.  Add 28 to the number that works (payload) to get the MTU.

Comment: I'll try that tonight and report back.

Comment: Does this have to be done over the VPN? If not, I've just done it on the actual network and the MTU comes back fine at 1472

Comment: Over the VPN connection.  Most VPN have a lower MTU that a standard ethernet.  If you can lower the MTU of the remote computer network  connection and the issue is improved, that usually means there is some type of MTU mismatch.

Comment: Just tested out the pinging from home now, and I have to go down to 1372 before I get a reply, so adding 28 to this brings me to a nice round 1400. Do I need to set this on the remote PC? I'll give it a try anyhow.

Comment: After checking "netsh interface ipv4 show subinterfaces", it seems my vpn connection is already set to 1400, but my "Wireless Internet Connection" is set to 1500. So by setting the wireless connection to 1400 too, should this solve the problem? (Incidentally the slow-saving issue occurs on a fixed desktop using an ethernet connection too, just in case you you were wondering)

Comment: Could be worth testing.

Answer (score 0):

As a test, to see if it can be localized a bit:

Lower the MTU of the client network connection to match the VPN MTU

Disable the advanced TCPIP features from an elevated command prompt:

```
netsh interface tcp set global autotuninglevel = disabled
netsh interface tcp set global rss = disabled
netsh interface tcp set global chimney = disabled
netsh interface tcp set global netdma = disabled
```

Something else you can try is to disable the Delayed Acknowledgment feature.  By default, Windows has a 200 ms timer and waits until there are two acks outstanding before sending data.  Applications that send a lot of small packets may incur performance penalties when this feature is enabled.  The following registry setting may be used to disable the feature.

```
Key: HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces\<Interface GUID>   
Value: TcpAckFrequency
Value Data: 1 (dword)
```